# How to add url's by deafult in create a jazz repository connection under location URI in eclipse rcp application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rational-team-concert

I am using existing `org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench` as an application in .product. One using 3.x Compatibility Layer (3.x API) on Eclipse 4.x. My platform is 4.16.

`plugin_customization.ini` file is added as property value of `preferenceCustomization` under `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point in application plugin

I have add below lines into `plugin_customization.ini` file but it is not updating `com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui.prefs` file

```
com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui/com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui.RepositoryCreationPart/dialog/uri/history0/value=<URL>
com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui/com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui.RepositoryCreationPart/dialog/uri/history1/value=<URL>
```

Create a jazz connection:

[image: Create a jazz connection]

Comment: Note the plugin_customization.ini sets default values. It does **not** update any prefs file.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong, because in my one of old workspace whenever i add above key and value into plugin_customization.ini it is getting updated into  com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui.prefs file.

Comment: **Note the plugin_customization.ini sets default values** - but the value should be stored somewhere right? or will directly read from plugin_customization.ini?

Comment: The plugin_customization.ini is read during startup and values are kept in memory, they are not written out. If you open one of the preference pages the page may end up writing the value to the prefs file.